# Passing JavaScript object to Sqlite with Flask

Tags: python, post, flask

I'm creating a web based point of sale system.  You press a few buttons and and a javascript object is created that contains the item name, price, and quantity.  I want for the user to click "Submit Order" button and the javascript object is passed to the sqllite database.

My issue is that the data is not in in an html form.  Is there any way I can pass the data to sqlite without a form post? Is there a different type of post I can do?

This is what I think I could do if I were using forms:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def home():
    b = get_db()
    db.execute('insert into orders (name, price, quantity) values (?, ?, ?)',
                 [request.form['id'], request.form['price'], request.form['quantity']])
    db.commit()
    return redirect(url_for('thankyou.html'))
```

Comment: You can pass it any way you like. If it's in JSON, then you should deserialize the JSON object and extract the data you need for insertion.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So it would be something like `request.get_json`, some parsing and then putting it into the sqlite db?